# Alfresco Process Services - ERROR when configuring Alfresco repository w/ basic authentication

Tags: authentication, process, alfresco, aps

I am trying to configure an Alfresco repository connection using basic authentication in Alfresco Process Services. However, I get the following error appear when I attempt to authorise an account with the connection.

```
Could not save account details: UNEXPECTED com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('&lt;' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')&#10; at [Source: (org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
```

- [Authorise Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsOfJ.png)
- [Alfresco Repository Configuration Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoscK.png)

I am running APS and Content Services using their docker images configured within docker-compose files, and the APS container logs show more detail about the error. It seems the API response is returning HTML instead of the expected JSON

```
2023-10-29 12:14:25 12:14:25 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR com.activiti.alfrescoconnector.service.AlfrescoServicesImpl  - error while reading response
2023-10-29 12:14:25 com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
2023-10-29 12:14:25  at [Source: (org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
2023-10-29 12:14:25     at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:2391)
2023-10-29 12:14:25     at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:735)
2023-10-29 12:14:25     at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:659)
2023-10-29 12:14:25     at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2737)
```

**APS docker-compose.yml file**

```
version: '3'
services:
  aps:
    image: alfresco/process-services:2.3.1
    environment:
      ACTIVITI_DATASOURCE_DRIVER: org.postgresql.Driver
      ACTIVITI_HIBERNATE_DIALECT: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
      ACTIVITI_LICENSE_MULTI_TENANT: false
      ACTIVITI_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/activiti
      ACTIVITI_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: alfresco
      ACTIVITI_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: alfresco
      ACTIVITI_CORS_ENABLED: true
      ACTIVITI_CSRF_DISABLED: true
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
    volumes:
      - ./activiti.lic:/usr/local/tomcat/lib/activiti.lic:ro
      - ./activiti-app.properties:/usr/local/tomcat/lib/activiti-app.properties
  
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.1
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: alfresco
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: alfresco
      POSTGRES_DB: activiti
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    volumes:
      - ./db-data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

ACS docker-compose.yml **(NOTE: this is a snippet of the file)**

```
version: "2"
services:
  alfresco:
    image: quay.io/alfresco/alfresco-content-repository:7.4.1.1
    mem_limit: 1900m
    environment:
      JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: >-
        -Dencryption.keystore.type=JCEKS
        -Dencryption.cipherAlgorithm=DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding
        -Dencryption.keyAlgorithm=DESede
        -Dencryption.keystore.location=/usr/local/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/keystore/keystore
        -Dmetadata-keystore.password=mp6yc0UD9e
        -Dmetadata-keystore.aliases=metadata
        -Dmetadata-keystore.metadata.password=oKIWzVdEdA
        -Dmetadata-keystore.metadata.algorithm=DESede
      JAVA_OPTS: >-
        -Ddb.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
        -Ddb.username=alfresco
        -Ddb.password=alfresco
        -Ddb.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/alfresco
        -Dsolr.host=solr6
        -Dsolr.port=8983
        -Dsolr.secureComms=secret
        -Dsolr.sharedSecret=secret
        -Dsolr.base.url=/solr
        -Dindex.subsystem.name=solr6
        -Dshare.host=127.0.0.1
        -Dshare.port=8080
        -Dalfresco.host=localhost
        -Dalfresco.port=8080
        -Daos.baseUrlOverwrite=http://localhost:8080/alfresco/aos
        -Dmessaging.broker.url="failover:(nio://activemq:61616)?timeout=3000&jms.useCompression=true"
        -Ddeployment.method=DOCKER_COMPOSE
        -Dtransform.service.enabled=true
        -Dtransform.service.url=http://transform-router:8095
        -Dsfs.url=http://shared-file-store:8099/
        -DlocalTransform.core-aio.url=http://transform-core-aio:8090/
        -Dcsrf.filter.enabled=false
        -Ddsync.service.uris=http://localhost:9090/alfresco
        -XX:MinRAMPercentage=50
        -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80
    volumes:
      - ./license:/usr/local/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/license
  transform-router:
    mem_limit: 512m
    image: quay.io/alfresco/alfresco-transform-router:3.0.0
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS: >-
        -XX:MinRAMPercentage=50
        -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80
      ACTIVEMQ_URL: nio://activemq:61616
      CORE_AIO_URL: http://transform-core-aio:8090
      FILE_STORE_URL: >-
        http://shared-file-store:8099/alfresco/api/-default-/private/sfs/versions/1/file
    ports:
      - "8095:8095"
    links:
      - activemq

  share:
    image: quay.io/alfresco/alfresco-share:7.4.1.1
    mem_limit: 1g
    environment:
      REPO_HOST: "alfresco"
      REPO_PORT: "8080"
      JAVA_OPTS: >-
        -XX:MinRAMPercentage=50
        -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80
        -Dalfresco.host=localhost
        -Dalfresco.port=8080
        -Dalfresco.context=alfresco
        -Dalfresco.protocol=http
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.4
    mem_limit: 512m
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=alfresco
      - POSTGRES_USER=alfresco
      - POSTGRES_DB=alfresco
    command: postgres -c max_connections=300 -c log_min_messages=LOG
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

I have as many things as I could think of including:

- Followed the APS documentation to connect to content services exactly.
- Testing different APS and ACS image versions.
- Different environment variable configurations and settings within the docker-compose image.
- Different postgres database versions.
- Tested different configurations within the activiti-app.properties file.
- Tested the relevant ACS api endpoints on Postman

I have spent hours upon hours testing different things, but the same error appears every time. So I have resorted to posting my first Stack Overflow post to see if anyone could help or provide me with some guidance :)

Note: I had to remove some content because Stack Overflow thinks its Spam.